# Getting the same value while using foreach in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, echo

I have a row named trailers in a MySQL database and I am querying that table using PHP and storing the result of that query in a variable. After that ,I am using a foreach loop to parse through each value of the variable i.e. each and every trailer value in the table.

But the problem is, when I try to echo the values of the variable only the first value of the variable is getting echoed in place of all other value. This is the query.

```
$query1 = "SELECT title,img,ratings,star_cast,director,trailer,imdb_ratings,lifetime_collecton,whats_good,whats_bad,watch_or_not 
    FROM recent_movies";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1);
```

This is the code of the for each loop

```
<?php 
foreach($result1 as $r):
    echo $r['trailer'];
endforeach;
?>
```

[image: This is how the output looks like]

Ten same values are getting printed instead of 10 different values.

Comment: Mysqli_query returns true or false.  Use mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: You need to fetch the data before you loop through it !!!

Comment: @Akin It returns a `mysqli_result` for a `SELECT` query.

Comment: @ForDev `mysqli_result` implements `Traversable`, so you can use it with `foreach`.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Using `foreach` with `mysqli_result` was added in 5.4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mysqli_fetch_array` function to retrieve rows from a mysqli resultset.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

---

```
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1);
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
     echo "<br> " . $row['title'] . " " . $row['ratings'] ;
 }
```

Comment: `echo "<br>" .  $row['title'] . " " . $row['ratings'];` ;-) what you have now will throw a parse error. Least, I *think* lol

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php says: **5.4.0  Iterator support was added, as mysqli_result now implements Traversable.**

Comment: I don't think this'll work, you gotta put `$row['title']` and `$row['ratings']` into curly braces (i.e. `{$row['ratings']}`)

Comment: @Fred-ii... please excuse my bad habitual Perl tendencies.  I have made a correction. (Maybe I should stick to answering Perl DBI/DBD questions.)

Comment: @spencer7593 hehe, not a problem, just thought I'd let you know. And please continue with what you do and not limit yourself to other areas ;-) *Cheers*